# Cannot merge Ocelot config files

Tags: ocelot

As per the [documentation](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html#merging-configuration-files) i tried to merge my config files so they are a bit more readable. The generated ocelot.json file however is not like expected. My folder structure is like follows:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37hIH.png)

Below is a text representation of this:

```
.
└── Ocelot route configs
    ├── ocelot.pokemon.json
    ├── ocelot.tweet.json
    └── ocelot.weather.json
```

The ocelot.pokemon.json file looks like following (the others are similar to this):

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v2/pokemon",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "pokeapi.co",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/pokemon",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "MyTestKey",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v2/pokemon/ditto",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "pokeapi.co",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/pokemon/ditto",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The generated ocelot.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "Routes": [
  ],
  "DynamicRoutes": [
  ],
  "Aggregates": [
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": null,
    "ServiceDiscoveryProvider": {
      "Scheme": null,
      "Host": null,
      "Port": 0,
      "Type": null,
      "Token": null,
      "ConfigurationKey": null,
      "PollingInterval": 0,
      "Namespace": null
    },
    "RateLimitOptions": {
      "ClientIdHeader": "ClientId",
      "QuotaExceededMessage": null,
      "RateLimitCounterPrefix": "ocelot",
      "DisableRateLimitHeaders": false,
      "HttpStatusCode": 429
    },
    "QoSOptions": {
      "ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking": 0,
      "DurationOfBreak": 0,
      "TimeoutValue": 0
    },
    "BaseUrl": null,
    "LoadBalancerOptions": {
      "Type": null,
      "Key": null,
      "Expiry": 0
    },
    "DownstreamScheme": null,
    "HttpHandlerOptions": {
      "AllowAutoRedirect": false,
      "UseCookieContainer": false,
      "UseTracing": false,
      "UseProxy": true,
      "MaxConnectionsPerServer": 2147483647
    },
    "DownstreamHttpVersion": null
  }
}
```

As you can see, the routes I defined were not added. I tried looking on the internet for this specific issue but couldn't find anything. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your different route configuration files are located in a folder you should make sure the correct overload of the AddOcelot method is called. In this case the method should be called with the folder name containing the route files.

For example:

```cs
config.AddOcelot("Ocelot route configs", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment)
```

Comment: This was indeed the answer, thank you very much :)

Comment: How can I get json files from diffrent folders?like this scrutcture XFolder->ocelot.x.json  ,YFolder-> ocelot.y.json

Comment: Hey @captainblack, as per the documentation of Ocelot, it should just work fine as long as the files are prefixed with "ocelot." and end with ".json". So your files should be used during configuration, if it doesn't work maybe you should create another Stackoverflow post where people can help you on your specific problem

Answer (score 3):

##### UPDATE: `.NET Core 3+` with `Ocelot 17.0.0`

As the method `AddOcelot` needs an `IWebHostEnvironment`, and this is not available in `HostBuilderContext`:

[image]

You need to get it via `WebHostBuilderContext`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created two different directories Development and Production and with the below code, I'm able to read ocelot configuration according to development environment to generate the final ocelot.json that will be use by ocelot middleware.

[image]